# URL parameter not updating when using apex params

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, url

We have a Lightning component hosted inside a Visualforce page to select multiple insurance carriers. When you enter the member ID for a carrier, it fires a Lightning event that is handled by the Visualforce page which then uses an ActionFunction to pass it to the controller through the URL.

The primary carrier updates successfully, but any subsequent selections copy the primary carrier's member ID. Checking through console logs the Lightning event is firing the correct carrier level (primary, secondary, etc..) and member ID and the Visualforce is receiving it properly, **but the member ID in the URL stays as the primary carrier's member ID**. The weird thing about this is that the carrier level updates properly, so we know the URL is at least partially updating. Please see the URLs and code samples below.

URL After Entering Primary Carrier Member ID as 333

> /apex/PatientNew?AJAXREQUEST=_viewRoot&**carrierNumber=Primary**&CF00NA00000018gkG=Test+Data+Incorporated&CF00NA00000018gkG_lkid=0012F00000DQh4S&com.salesforce.visualforce.ViewStateCSRF=VmpFPSxNakF4T0Mwd05DMHdPVlF4TkRvME5UbzFOUzQwTVRCYSx6WUFNMlAySFE1WDNqMVlaT1VaS0JSLE9USXdOREV5&com.salesforce.visualforce.ViewStateVersion=201804041759310272&ent=01IA0000000R9fn&groupId=888&inputAddress=&inputCity=&inputName=&inputPayerId=&inputState=&inputSubtype=Medicaid&inputZipCode=&j_id0%3AtheForm=j_id0%3AtheForm&j_id0%3AtheForm%3Aj_id131%3AcarrierBlock%3Aj_id153=j_id0%3AtheForm%3Aj_id131%3AcarrierBlock%3Aj_id153&j_id0%3AtheForm%3Aj_id131%3Aj_id144%3Aj_id145=&j_id0%3AtheForm%3Aj_id131%3Aj_id159%3Aj_id163=&j_id0%3AtheForm%3Aj_id131%3AproviderBlock%3Aj_id138%3Aphy=0032F000009dxN3QAI&**memberId=333**&RecordType=012A0000000Hacl&retURL=%2F0012F00000DQh4S&save_new=1&scontrolCaching=1&sfdc.override=1

URL After Entering Secondary Carrier Member ID as 444

> /apex/PatientNew?AJAXREQUEST=_viewRoot&**carrierNumber=Secondary**&CF00NA00000018gkG=Test+Data+Incorporated&CF00NA00000018gkG_lkid=0012F00000DQh4S&com.salesforce.visualforce.ViewStateCSRF=VmpFPSxNakF4T0Mwd05DMHdPVlF4TkRvME9Ub3hPQzQzTURCYSxFVDdHWUtsQVlROTJvLXBERHFIYlFOLE9USXdOREV5&com.salesforce.visualforce.ViewStateVersion=201804041759310272&device=01tA0000000MAMNIA4&ent=01IA0000000R9fn&groupId=888&inputAddress=&inputCity=&inputName=&inputPayerId=&inputState=&inputSubtype=Medicaid&inputZipCode=&j_id0%3AtheForm=j_id0%3AtheForm&j_id0%3AtheForm%3Aj_id131%3AcarrierBlock%3Aj_id153=j_id0%3AtheForm%3Aj_id131%3AcarrierBlock%3Aj_id153&j_id0%3AtheForm%3Aj_id131%3Aj_id144%3Aj_id145=&j_id0%3AtheForm%3Aj_id131%3Aj_id159%3Aj_id163=01tA0000000MAMNIA4&j_id0%3AtheForm%3Aj_id131%3AproviderBlock%3Aj_id138%3Aphy=0032F000009dxN3QAI&**memberId=333**&RecordType=012A0000000Hacl&retURL=%2F0012F00000DQh4S&save_new=1&scontrolCaching=1&sfdc.override=1

Visualforce Page

```
<script>
    $Lightning.use("c:CarrierSearchTerms", function() {
        $Lightning.createComponent("c:PayerTableContainer", {}, "lightning",
            function(cmp) {
                $A.eventService.addHandler({"event" : "c:UpdatePayerTableInsuranceIds", "handler" : handleInsuranceUpdate});
            }
        );
    });
</script>
<script>
    var handleInsuranceUpdate = function(event){
        handleInsuranceIdUpdate(event.getParam("carrierNumber"), event.getParam("memberId"), event.getParam("groupId"));
        // Debugs at this point are correct for both carrierNumber and memberId.
    }                          
</script>   
<apex:actionFunction name="handleInsuranceIdUpdate" action="{!handleInsuranceIdUpdate}" reRender="">
    <apex:param name="carrierNumber" value=""/>
    <apex:param name="memberId" value=""/>
    <apex:param name="groupId" value=""/>
</apex:actionFunction>
```

Apex Controller

```
......    
public void handleInsuranceIdUpdate() {
        String carrierNumber = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('carrierNumber');
        String memberId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('memberId');
        String groupId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('groupId');
        System.debug(ApexPages.currentPage().getURL()); //Debug for URLs provided before
        // Debuging at this point shows the correct carrierNumber, 
        // but the memberId and groupId are always the primary carrier's member and group IDs
        ......
    }
```

Comment: does the `rerender` attribute on the actionfunction have a value in it in your page markup?

Comment: If not, does the observed behavior change if you put in `rerender="foo"`?

Comment: I do not have a value in the rerender attribute. What would you recommend me rerendering in this case?

Comment: it does not actually have to rerender anything real, just put some value in that attribute so it isn't blank.

Comment: unfortunately the issue still persists when giving a random value to that attribute